# Working with pending trigger event in Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, postgresql

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def action_init_address_receipt(cls, request):
    execute_sql('alter table finance_addressreceipts disable trigger user;')
    execute_sql('select init_address_receipt();')

    # next line below is where I get the pending trigger event Error
    execute_sql('alter table finance_addressreceipts enable trigger user;')
    return {'message': 'well done'}
```

I did some research and it appears that I need to do this in two separate transactions. I wonder if there are some better, elegant solutions to this.

Comment: Start a transaction and then commit with your hands

Comment: alright, I already did this, I just wonder if there is a better way

Comment: I have some transactions in plain SQL which enable and disable triggers internally during certain operations.  I haven'd had a problem like this.  What does this trigger do?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so typically this error occurs when previous statements in a transaction have created pending trigger events (these include foreign key references).  Typically you want to make sure:

1. any `alter table` queries are near the beginning of the transaction, and
2. you are aware of how the entire transaction flow runs.